# To Run java project

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, server, project

How to run a java project without any IDE, like am giving you remote server and java project you should run without any IDE. I recently faced this question in interview

I tried cmd but it failed. Can you explain clearly step by step procedure

Comment: It's the same as running the project on a local PC. Use a java compiler to compile the project (The "javac" command), then execute the resulting jar file as normal. Install a java compiler and runtime as needed. What did you try in CMD? What failed?

Answer (score 3):

From your question's tags i assume you got a Spring-boot application which should be deployed on `Tomcat` Server.

If you have a project built on Spring-boot and you have the access to your remote server.

You can use build tools like `Maven` or `Gradle` and you can use those tools to simply build a `jar` or `war` of your project from `CommandLine` commands and then you can simply deploy the built `jar` to your remote server container for example your `Tomcat` Server.

Comment: Not a springboot project,? What if project is j2EE?